# How much time do you have to accept the game?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was unable to find this information anywhere. When you're trying to join a game, at certain point the accept loading screen appears. You must click the accept button.

After certain time, if you or somebody else fails to accept, the group is torn away and the search for game continues. How long is that time?

Comment: It is encouraged that you guys accompany your votes with comments. I will gladly improve the question.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because this is something really easy to test; part of the title text for downvotes indicates it's an appropriate action if *the question does not show any research effort*.

Comment: Probably. If someone answers it means he did test it, wich is the same thing you could yourself.
If you are going to test it you should then answer your own post to post the results.

Comment: Only -2 and +18 needed to get @666nordless666 a Reversal badge :p

Comment: To test it, I would have to join the queue and then decline a game. That would piss off 9 other people. I just didn't think it's worth it.

Comment: @TomášZato Or you can accept it right before the time is out. Easy enough...

Comment: I didn't want to play.

Comment: I don't think you guys should downvote him - he is asking a legitimate question, and isn't in a position to test it out for himself.

Answer (score 6):

You have 10 seconds to accept the game.